# How to get range of a GLib.Settings

Tags: gtk3, vala

Normally I use below code to get string from an GLib.Settings.

```
    var ss = new GLib.Settings ("org.gnome.system.proxy");
    string sm = ss.get_string ("mode");
```

now I want get the range like this in bash.

```
⭕ gsettings range org.gnome.system.proxy mode
enum
'none'
'manual'
'auto'
```

When search thr valadoc.org, the `GLib.Settings.get_range` was deprecated. It says need use `GLib.SettingsSchemaKey.get_range` instead.

But the `GLib.SettingsSchemaKey` `GLib.SettingsSchema` `GLib.SettingsSchemaSource` mess me up.

It seems I can use `SettingsSchema.get_key (string name).get_range ()` to get the range. but how can I get this `SettingsSchema`?

---

With Mühlenhoff' help, I write an example code, half success.

```
void check(){
    SettingsSchemaSource sss = GLib.SettingsSchemaSource.get_default ();
    SettingsSchema schema = sss.lookup ("org.gnome.system.proxy", true);    // bool recursive
    if (schema == null) {print ("ID not found."); return;}

    if(schema.has_key ("mode")){
        SettingsSchemaKey ssk = schema.get_key ("mode");
        Variant v = ssk.get_range();
        size_t length = 0;
        print("name: %s\n", ssk.get_name());    //mode
        print ("range: '%s', %s\n", v.get_string (out length), length.to_string());
//      print ("'%s', %"+size_t.FORMAT+"\n", v.get_string (out length), length);
    }else{ print("no key found: mode\n"); return;}

    GLib.Settings settings = new GLib.Settings.full (schema, null, null);
    string greeting = settings.get_string ("mode");
    print("current mode: %s\n", greeting);
}
```

the output:

```
name: mode

(list-exec:3899): GLib-CRITICAL **: 16:13:08.313: g_variant_get_string: assertion 'g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_STRING) || g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_OBJECT_PATH) || g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_SIGNATURE)' failed
range: '(null)', 0
current mode: auto
```

It seems due to this **deprecated**, we need to analyze and process a very complex data structure (GVariant) by ourselves. It would waste a lot of code.

I have encountered similar things when dealing with `libsvg`. :(

Answer (score 3):

You can get a `SettingsSchemaKey` from a `SettingsSchema` and a `SettingsSchema` from a `SettingsSchemaSource`.

To get a `SettingsSchemaSource`, you can either call `SettingsSchemaSource.get_default ()` or `SettingsSchemaSource.from_directory ()`.

[get_default ()](https://valadoc.org/gio-2.0/GLib.SettingsSchemaSource.get_default.html) is a static method that will get you the system schema source.

[from_directory ()](https://valadoc.org/gio-2.0/GLib.SettingsSchemaSource.SettingsSchemaSource.from_directory.html) is a constructor that will get you a schema source from a file system directory that you have to specify.

Comment: sure, I missed `SettingsSchemaSource.get_default`.